# Get jsonArray Using Native query entity manager

Tags: java, json, spring, java-8, hibernate-entitymanager

I have an service class as below:

```
public class RulesService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public  JSONArray getReportingTableData(String Query) {
        List<Object> list = em.createNativeQuery(Query).getResultList();

        return /*convert the above list as json array**/;
    }
}
```

So, if the query is "select col1 as name,col2 as agefrom table1" then my jsonArray should be

```
[{"name":"test","age":"24"},{"name":"test1","age":"26"}]
```

I don't want to use pojo or entity class here, because the query will get change dynamically and there are many number of tables here, so I don't want to create seperate java class for each table.That is the reason am trying to make it as a JSONArray.

Can anyone please give me the right solution do it.

Comment: why have not used `List<Map<String,Integer>>` ?

Comment: I dont think your getResultList would work. It returns List<Object[]>

Comment: You can also use SQL-calls to obtain the wanted data. These are flexible.

Comment: @HadiJ I have tried it as Prathamesh Jagtap  said the getResultList returns List<Object[]> . So am not able to get it as a key-value pair. It's just give the array of value

Comment: `"age:26"` should be `"age":"26"`

Comment: I edited it.Thanks @HadiJ

Comment: Did you try with `ObjectMapper` that i posted as answer?

Comment: @HadiJ As I said earlier am not able to get the result list as key value pair. It's just like [["test","24"],["test2","26"]

Comment: if you have list of array and want to convert it to `key/value` you can do like this. `List<Map<String,String>> result = list.stream()
                .map(arr->{
                    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("name",arr[0]);
                    map.put("age",arr[1]);
                    return map;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with Jackson's ObjectMapper. This [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) is very interesting.

```
List<Object> list = em.createNativeQuery(Query).getResultList();
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.writeValue(out, list);

final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
System.out.println(new String(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ObjectMapper to do dynamically.

```
public  JSONArray getReportingTableData(String Query) {
    List<Object> list = em.createNativeQuery(Query).getResultList();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String arrayToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(arrayToJson);

    return /*convert the above list as json array**/;
}
```

Comment: It converting my list<Object> to jsonArray , but my query is not returning it as a key value pair.Any suggestion to do it

Comment: replace em.createNativeQuery(Query); to

   Map<String, Object> resultMap = em.createNativeQuery(Query, Map.class).getResultList();

Comment: can you share mysql query

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do like bellow. your query result is list of array. `[["test","24"],["test2","26"]]` and you want to convert it to `key-value`

```
List<Map<String,String>> result = listOfarray.stream()
                          .map(arr->{
                              Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();  
                              map.put("name",arr[0]); 
                              map.put("age",arr[1]); 
                              return map; 
                            })
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: As I informed earlier, the query is dynamic , column name for each query can also change .Will not be able to get the column name during processing

Comment: You can have a method that give query result and columns name. then convert it as you see in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I might be late but someone might find this interesting and save his/her day.
Reference
[https://gist.github.com/baxtheman/44fd1601380d415eeec53d9e6d5587dc][1]

```
public List<ObjectNode> getQuery(
    Integer anno,
    Integer settimana) {

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
        "NATIVE SQL....",Tuple.class);

    List<Tuple> results = q.getResultList();

    List<ObjectNode> json = _toJson(results);

    return json;
}

private List<ObjectNode> _toJson(List<Tuple> results) {

    List<ObjectNode> json = new ArrayList<ObjectNode>();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    for (Tuple t : results)
    {
        List<TupleElement<?>> cols = t.getElements();

        ObjectNode one = mapper.createObjectNode();

        for (TupleElement col : cols)
        {
            one.put(col.getAlias(), t.get(col.getAlias()).toString());
        }

        json.add(one);
    }

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a late answer but got it when i needed it.
The pretty easy and simple thing worked for me is

```
String[] columns = {"id","name","salary","phone","address", "dob"};
String query = "SELECT id,name,salary,phone,address,dob from users ";

List<Object[]> queryResp = em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();

List<Map<String,String>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object[] obj : queryResp) {
    Map<String,String> row = new HashMap<>(columns.length);
    for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
        if(obj[i]!=null)
            row.put(columns[i], obj[i].toString());
        else
            row.put(columns[i], "");
    }
    dataList.add(row);
}

//Creating the ObjectMapper object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//Converting the Object to JSONString
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataList);
```